# MPMoviePlayer crashing on getting out and in the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mpmovieplayer

I get this error:

```
-[MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController player]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e63fe90
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController player]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e63fe90'
```

Using iOS 8, the language is Objective-C. But I have this same code in the `if statement` like this in `applicationDidBecomeActive` and it does not crash:

```
UIViewController *vc = ((UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController).visibleViewController;
    if([vc isKindOfClass:[VideoViewController class]]) {
            VideoViewController *vca = vc;
        if(vca.player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused){
            [vca.player play];
        }
```

But if I use it on the different MPMoviePlayer, and it is fullscreen. I switch to a different app, and back, it crashes. Buy why not with the other movie controller. Also, the other one does not show any playback controls, while this one which crashes does.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are calling 'player' on a MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController object... ?

Comment: no, you mean like this [InlineVideoFullscreenViewController player], no!
I searched the code over and over again. If the player is not full screen, and if switch in and out, it does not crash, It only crashes in full-screen.

Comment: Look at the above code, you are using vca.player. So, it might be that vca might not be the class you were expecting. That is why the isKindOfClass:, prevents exception.

Comment: @k6sandeep It is the VideoViewController Class. Like i said it only crashes in full screen, not when it is embedded.

Comment: Well then you can expect that full screen is different viewcontroller, not the same VideoViewController.

Comment: @k6sandeep Wow, opener. Can you please let me know how to find out the class name, like what is the method. That would be helpful, if it works, you can give the answer and I will tick you off as the correct answer

Comment: Well you said that it crashes, you know the class name from the above exception 'MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController', but I am not sure if that is private class and you might not be able to access api for it.

Comment: @k6sandeep unable to access it, I tried it! Let me see if I can make the view, screenbounds, you see what I mean

Comment: @k6sandeep Does not work, because you cannot go back. You can always tell the user!